# Cytoscape compound layout top to bottom issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cytoscape.js

Currently having an issue with my layout while using Cytoscape library `breadthfirst`
I am using compound node but this has kind of made my layout wrong.

I would look it to follow the following design

[image]

Here is my code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-architecture-hozmf

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It might not be supporting compound nodes. Use a layout algorithm with compound support. You can check fcose https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-fcose/

Comment: Just updated the code, it still doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: layout algorithms can be very complex. Fcose is a complex one. It tries to give you the best possible way. You can try adding "constraints" inside fcose. Read fcose